# ZKEmkeeper: Events not triggering on Windows Service

Tags: windows, service

I'm stucked for a while trying to use zkemkeeper sdk to use on a Windows Service that uses a InBios(Controller) for fingerprint.
i first connect to the device and then i add the event OnAttTransactionEx, someone can point me what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the code snippet
`

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
       Thread TT = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkedThread));
                TT.IsBackground = true;
                TT.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                this.isServiceStarted = true;
                TT.Start(); 
}

 private void WorkedThread()
 {           
              
      WriteToFile("Worker Thread Started.");                
                
      ZKemClient objZkeeper = new ZKemClient(filepath);
      this.isDeviceConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net("19x.x.x.24x", 4370);

   if (this.isDeviceConnected)
   {
       WriteToFile("Device connected.");
       WriteToFile("While loop execution starting.");
       while (true)
       {
          WriteToFile(filepath, "While loop execution started.");
       }

   }
   else
   {
       WriteToFile("Failed to connect to Device.");
    }
}

// ZMClient class
 public bool Connect_Net(string IPAdd, int Port)
 {
     bool bResult = false;
     try
     {
         // Actual SDK class
         CZKEM objCZKEM = new CZKEM();
         if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
         {                   
            if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))
            {
              // [ Register your events here ]
                    
              objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
             }
             bResult = true;
         }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       WriteToFile("Connect_Net() Exception->" + ex.Message);                              
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

After playing a lot with threading, found a solution.

1. For windows service - Add reference to System.Windows.Forms
2. Thread TT1 = new Thread(() =>
   {
   this.objCZKEM = new CZKEM();
   Application.Run();
   });
   TT1.IsBackground = true;
   TT1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   TT1.Start();
3. Simply continue with current thread

   if (this.objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IP, 4370))
   {
   this.WriteToFile("ZKEM device connected");

   ```
     if (this.objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))
     {
          this.WriteToFile("ZKEM device events registration started");
          // [ Register your events here ]

          this.objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += new _IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx);
          this.WriteToFile("Done with ZKEM device events registration.");
   ```

   }

You should not able to receive finger events from device.